# Retrieve array of images from Firestore

Tags: image, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, uri

I made a query to take all the fields of a specific document from Firestore. One of those fields is an array of images, taken from the Firebase Storage. I don't know why, but i can't retrieve those images.

**EDIT: I tried to add a  abc  after the log, before the image, nothing shows.**

Here my code:

```
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      handlClick();
  }, []);

  const handlClick = () => {
    var i = 0;
    setRestaurant([]);
    setPhoto([]);
    db.doc(idBranch).get().then(data => {
        const branchData = data.data();
        setRestaurant(branchData);
        const ph = branchData.Photo;
        ph.forEach(pho =>{
          setPhoto(p => [...p, pho]);
        })
    })
  }

  return (
        {photo && photo.forEach((ph) => {
            <View>
              <Text> {console.log(ph)}</Text>
              <Image source = {{uri : ph}}/>
            </View>
        })}
  )
```

The console.log is correct (even if they are retrieved more than one times each and shouldn't do that), here the image:
[image]

Here the Firestore structure:

[image]

Please, help me to understand what I should do to retrieve the images.

Comment: Try adding style in <Image /> adding style={{width: 200, height: 200})

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: I don't think it's an image problem, i edit the question, i add text but still nothing shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functional component must return JSX but not the object. Also you must use `.map` method if you want to render JSX via loop. Try this:

```
return (
   <View>
      {photo && photo.map((ph) => (
         <View>
            <Text>{console.log(ph)}</Text>
            <Image source = {{uri : ph}}/>
         </View>
         ))
      }
   </View>
)
```